# Filter one array using a 2nd array, and display the results on a spreadsheet

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, array-filter

----- BACKGROUND ----- In Google Sheets/Apps Script, I'm trying to move some transaction data from one sheet and organize it on a different sheet with subtotal rows for each customer account (called "Units") with a grand total at the bottom.

I have the transactions organized in an array of objects as key:value pairs ("transactions", the keys are headers, some values are strings, others are numbers), and I have the units in a 2nd array called "unitList". I want to iterate through each element in the unitList array, and pull each transaction with a matching unit onto my "targetSheet", then append a subtotal row for each unit.

----- UPDATE 10/7/2018 3:49PM EST -----

Thanks to everyone for your input - I took your advice and ditched the library I was using and instead found better getRowsData and appendRowsData functions which I put directly in my code project. **This fixed the array filter problem (verified by logging filterResults), BUT, now when I call appendRowsData(), I get this error:**

> The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid. (line 73, file "Display Transactions")

Line 73 is the line below, in the appendRowsData function. Any help on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

```
var destinationRange = sheet.getRange(firstDataRowIndex, 1, objects.length, 9);
```

Here's my project in it's entirety thus far:

```
function displayTransactions() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Label each sheet
  var dashboard = ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard');
  var unitsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Unit Ref Table');
  var transactionsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Transactions Ref Sheet');
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Target Sheet');

  // Returns true if the cell where cellData was read from is empty.
  // Arguments:
  //   - cellData: string
  function isCellEmpty(cellData) {
    return typeof(cellData) == "string" && cellData == "";
  }

  // Define function that converts arrays into JSON
  //   For every row of data in data, generates an object that contains the data.
  //   Names of object fields are defined in keys.
  // Arguments:
  //   - data: JavaScript 2d array
  //   - keys: Array of Strings that define the property names for the objects to create  
  function getObjects(data, keys) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
      var object = {};
      var hasData = false;
      for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; ++j) {
        var cellData = data[i][j];
        if (isCellEmpty(cellData)) {
          continue;
        }
        object[keys[j]] = cellData;
        hasData = true;
      }
      if (hasData) {
        objects.push(object);
      }
    }
    return objects;
  }

  // Define function that pulls spreadsheet data into arrays, then converts to JSON using getObjects function
  function getRowsData(sheet) {    
    var headersRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
    var headers = headersRange.getValues()[0];
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(sheet.getFrozenRows()+1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
    return getObjects(dataRange.getValues(), headers);
  }

  // Define function appendRowsData that uses getLastRow to fill in one row of data per object defined in the objects array.
  //   For every Column, it checks if data objects define a value for it.
  // Arguments:
  //   - sheet: the sheet object where the data will be written
  //   - objects: an array of objects, each of which contains data for a row

  function appendRowsData(sheet, objects) {
    var headersRange = sheet.getRange(7, 1, 1, 9);
    var firstDataRowIndex = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
    var headers = headersRange.getValues()[0];
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
      var values = []
      for (j = 0; j < headers.length; ++j) {
        var header = headers[j];
        values.push(header.length > 0 && objects[i][header] ? objects[i][header] : "");
      }
      data.push(values);
    }
    var destinationRange = sheet.getRange(firstDataRowIndex, 1, objects.length, 9);
    destinationRange.setValues(data);
  }

  // Call getRowsData on transactions sheet
  var transactions = getRowsData(transactionsSheet);

  // Get array of units
  var unitList = unitsSheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues();

  // Iterate through the unitList and pull all transactions with matching unit into the target sheet
  for (var i=0; i < unitList.length; i++) {
    var subTotal = 0;
    var grandTotal = 0;
    var filterResults = transactions.filter(function(x) {
      return x['Unit'] == unitList[i];      
    })

    Logger.log(filterResults); // This brings the correct results!  

    // Display matching transactions
    appendRowsData(targetSheet, filterResults);

    // Grand total at the bottom when i=units.length

  }
}
```

Comment: Here's a link to the GSheetsUtils library I'm using

https://labs.amplifiedit.com/docs/global.html

Comment: Are you sure there is a `Unit` header? Try `Logger.log(x.Unit)`

Comment: @Trevor, or at least Logger.log(transactions) to see what the properties are.

Comment: Logger.log(x.Unit) in the array filter function oddly does not yield anything ("No logs found. Use Logger API to add logs to your project.") BUT, the debugger shows each transaction object has the Unit key and the correct corresponding value.

The transactions on transactionsSheet sheet were pulled there via QUERY function in cell A1, which is where the "Unit" header value populates. Is it possible that getRowsData is successfully pulling the cell value ("Unit"), whereas the array filter only sees the function in that cell?

Comment: Logger.log(transactions) successfully logs the transactions.

Comment: @Trevor, wrap your code in a try {} catch(err) { Logger.log(err); } block to see if it catches anything

Comment: Any stray space around "Unit"?  Try `x["Unit"]` with spaces if present. (Also, I don't see any reason to use this library. Is it open source? I don't think it has been updated since 2016...)

Comment: What line raises the error?

Comment: After just updating this thread, I had a thought - could this be a scope issue? When I call appendRowsData within my array filter, is it the case that the filterResults argument variable isn't accessible by the appendRowsData function?

I'll try moving appendRowsData to be within my for loop and see if that works.

Comment: I moved appendRowsData to be within the for loop, but I'm still getting this error:

The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid.

Comment: @Trevor The parameters for `destinationRange` are "firstDataRowIndex" (Row), "1" (Column), "objects.length" (number of Rows), "9" (Number of Columns). What values are you getting for these parameters? I have a feeling that "objects.length" is returning a value of 0, and that is not a valid value for getRange.

Comment: @Tedinoz you were correct! The object wasn't being recognized when called - a quick change is all it took to fix, thank you.

My first real project is finally completed - thanks to everyone for your help!